# How to set the scroll position after disable the movement method to a EditText?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview, scrollview

I'm working on an EditText which has 1 line, but he has not enought space for display his text.
So by default the is displayed normaly but we can scroll just on the only 1 line.

I tryed to use this line

```
ed.setMovementMethod(null);
```

The scroll is disabled but he is on the top of the EditText.

On this picture, below we can see the EditText whithout the `setMovementMethod` but we can scroll:

[image: image1]

And on next image we can see the EditText with the `setMovementMethod` but the as you can see the scroll is at the top.

[image: image2]

I would like to disable the MovementMethod but put the scroll at the bottom for see the text correctly.
Someone can tell me if it's possible to do that or if i am forced to move all my xml work ?

Thank you, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Make this change

```
ed.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); 
ed.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```